# Regex on picking S3 bucket name from S3 URI

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to regex pattern to obtain S3 bucket name from S3 URI but have no luck.

example: `s3://example-bucket/file-name.filetype`

Closest I could get with this: `\/\/([^\/].*[^\/])\/` but i'm not sure how to negate the slash from the result

Comment: Try using this: `\/\/([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part `([^/]+)` is looking for a sequence of of characters that are not slash.
keeping close with what you had you could write `//([^/]+)/` but this is the same as

```
//([^/]+)
```

optional you could use lookbehind `(?<=//)` and/or lookahead `(?=/)`

```
(?<=//)([^/]+)(?=/)
```

(depending on your use cases a couple of different lookahead expressions are possible)

'lookaround' especially 'lookbehind' is not supported in all regexp dialects. e.g. not in JavaScript

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0yT3KC3WV0FhV9KW)

Comment: a lookbehind will work fine, as long as you aren't using javascript which has no lookbehind. (the likely case)

Comment: is there any benefit using lookahead/lookbehind over other method? Except that i personally find it more "readable", i guess?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the lookbehind option (javascript regex), and your URL structure is consistent enough, then perhaps this pattern will be useful:

`[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/])`

In English:  "match one or more non-forward slashes, followed (but not actually matched, via the lookahead) by one forward slash and a non-forward slash".

(your other option would be to access your match groups in order to get rid of the slashes that you matched)

https://regex101.com/r/XM05Sw/2/